# Codesigning - codesign exited with code 3, only on emulator

Tags: c#, ios, maui, codesign

For a small .Net MAUI project, when building to an emulator, the build output fails with the following error and stack trace:

```
Target "_CodesignAppBundle" skipped. Previously built successfully.
Target _CodesignVerify:
  Using "CodesignVerify" task from assembly "/usr/local/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.iOS.Sdk/16.2.29/tools/msbuild/iOS/../iOS/Xamarin.iOS.Tasks.dll".
  Task "CodesignVerify"
    Environment Variables passed to tool:
      CODESIGN_ALLOCATE=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
    /usr/bin/codesign --verify -vvvv "-R=anchor apple generic and certificate 1[field.1.2.840.113635.100.6.2.1] exists and (certificate leaf[field.1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.2] exists or certificate leaf[field.1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.4] exists)" bin/Debug/net6.0-ios/iossimulator-x64/App.Project.app 
    bin/Debug/net6.0-ios/iossimulator-x64/App.Project.app: valid on disk
    bin/Debug/net6.0-ios/iossimulator-x64/App.Project.app: satisfies its Designated Requirement
    test-requirement: code failed to satisfy specified code requirement(s)
    /usr/local/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.iOS.Sdk/16.2.29/tools/msbuild/iOS/Xamarin.Shared.targets(1930,3): error MSB6006: "codesign" exited with code 3.
  Done executing task "CodesignVerify" -- FAILED.
Done building target "_CodesignVerify" in project "App.Project.csproj" -- FAILED.

Done building project "App.Project.csproj" -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.

/usr/local/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.iOS.Sdk/16.2.29/tools/msbuild/iOS/Xamarin.Shared.targets(1930,3): error MSB6006: "codesign" exited with code 3.
    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)
```

I'm building through Visual Studio for Mac.
The project only has platform folders for iOS and Android.

The app builds fine to a local iOS device, connected via USB. I'm building to an iPhone SE. The error does not occur on a new Maui project.
Any suggestions for how I should approach this error? I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 1):

When you need deploy a .Net MAUI project to the simulator, please be attentive to the listed below:

1. In Solution Explorer, right-click on your .NET MAUI app project and select **Properties**. Then, navigate to the **iOS Bundle Signing** tab and ensure that **Scheme** is set to `Automatic Provisioning`.
2. You can only deploy .Net MAUI project with [iOS capabilities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/capabilities?view=net-maui-7.0&tabs=vsmac) which is added to your provisioning profile to physical iOS devices, not the simulator.
3. Try to **Delete** bin and obj folders and then rebuild it.